# I have a list splitting problem in Python

Tags: python, list, file, split, readfile

I'm reading a file into a list. Now I want, that every after coma which I have in my list, there should be a new index. By now, everything is placed in index 0.

relevanted Code:

```
def add_playlist():
playlist_file_new =filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=f'C:/Users/{Playlist.username}/Music',filetypes=[('Playlistdateien','.txt')])
with open (playlist_file_new,'r') as filenew:
    filenew_content = list(filenew.readlines())
    print(filenew_content[0])
```

So, what do I have to do, so that after every comma there starts a new index ?
Please help me and I thank you in advance. Also I'm sorry if this is a really basic question, I'm really new into programming.

Comment: So basically you new line character is a `,` not a `\n`. So instead of `readlines` use `read` so you'll have the whole data as a string. Then you can `split` the data by `,`.

Comment: What does the text file look like? If I have your input data I can provide a working answer.

Comment: Well the problem is, that then it only prints me one char, and not a whole string. So this whole line `'C:/Users/kevin/Music/y2meta.com - Big Boi - Kryptonite (VANE & ZVBXR Remix) (320 kbps).mp3'` becomes to "(" in index 0, " ' " in index1, the "C" in index 2 and so on. The code: 
`filenew_content = filenew.read()
 filenew_content.split(",")
 print(filenew_content[1])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't try your code but I would do it like this:

```
with open (playlist_file_new,'r') as filenew:
    filenew_content = filenew.read()
    filenew_content_list = filenew_content.split(",")
```

That reads the **complete** data (please be careful with files bigger than your working memory (RAM)) of your file into the variable `filenew_content`.
It is returned as a string. The string objects in Python have the method `split()`, where you can define a string where your bigger string should be splitted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `list()`, use `str.split()`. To do this, you can't use readlines(), as that returns a list of lines.

You're looking for something like this:

```
filenew_content = playlist_file_new.read().split(",")
```

This takes the file object, gets a string containing it's contents, and splits it into a list, using a comma as the separator.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what You want is `.split()` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to turn `list[str]` into `list[str, str, str…]`, you can use the `str.split(str)` method. See the following:

```py
l = ["hello,world,this,is,a,list"]
new_l = l[0].split(",")
print(new_l)
>>> ["hello", "world", "this", "is", "a". "list"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The string.split(',') method should work.
for example

```py
# loop over all the lines in the file
for line in filenew.readlines():
    items = line.strip().split(',')
    # strip strips the line of leading and trailing whitespace. 
    # split returns a tuple of all the strings created by 
    # splitting at the given character.

    # loop over all the items in the line
    for item in items:
        # add them to the list
        filenew_content.append(item)
```

See also: [Python documentation for strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)